# Как найти больше 1 переноса строки регулярным выражением в xcode?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, xcode, bash, shell, grep

Мне нужно найти лишние переносы строк в коде. Например если после `}` больше 1 переноса строки, то подсветить `warning`. Вот, что я пробовал:

```
TAGS="TODO:|FIXME:"
echo "searching ${SRCROOT} for ${TAGS}"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 `egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($TAGS)/ warning:\$1/"`

TAGS2="\s+$"
echo "searching ${SRCROOT} for ${TAGS2}"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0
egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS2).*\$" |
perl -p -e "s/($TAGS2)/ warning\$1/"
```

Первый скрипт подсвечивает все `TODO:` и `FIXME:` в коде, но никак не могу понять как правильно написать второй скрипт, чтобы подсвечивал больше 1 переноса строки после `}`.

Comment: Попробуйте так
`TAGS="TODO:|FIXME:|[\n]{2,}"`

Comment: а можно полюбопытствовать что вы такое делаете? типа code style check?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko да,устроился работать джуном, в каждом мердже у меня полно лишних newlinов и я за это получаю минусы, решил попробовать написать скрипт, который будет мне красными warningaми на них подсвечивать :)

Comment: ну знаете ли :) тогда может поможет http://objclean.com/ он правда 10 рублей стоит

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Ну я все таки постараюсь написать свой скрипт :) Так как я не внимателен только к лишним ньюлайнам.

Comment: @Alexander Спасибо, но не сработало :(

Comment: поиск шаблона, занимающего несколько строк, с помощью *grep* вполне [возможен](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7167115/4827341), но вот с нумерацией строк при этом, насколько я понимаю, ничего не выйдет. по-моему, тут одним лишь регулярным выражением не обойтись — нужна именно программа. возможностей *awk*, я думаю, хватит. а если вам знаком *perl*, так тем более. // метка *xcode*, вроде бы, не имеет к вопросу никакого отношения.

Comment: [man grep](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=grep) утверждает, что `-n, --line-number` добавляет номера строк

Comment: вы ж не ограничены грепом/башем, вы можете себе гитхук или линт-чекер написать хоть на пыхе, хоть на перле. например. https://gist.github.com/digitalist/ae33e199a69acd3d017ddd81b6b19908 (ищет строки которые добавились в текущем коммите и проверяет их на мусорку) Олсо, лишние ньюлайны у вас от привычки (избавьтесь от нее) или от неправильных настроек редактора (настройте его).

Comment: неужели в xcode все так плохо с автоформатированием?